# Will using the same database for client hashes, salts, and settings expose client hashes?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, hash

If I have an XML database on my web server;

```
<Database>
    <Client sid="0123456789abcdefg" name="John Doe" email="johndoe@mail.com" hash="9876543210abcdefg" salt="abcdefg9876543210">
        <Setting>A Setting</Setting>
        <Setting>Another Setting</Setting>
    </Client>
    ...
</Database>
```

And I log in with the hash and salt, retrieve the SID, and redirect to the home page via PHP;

```
header("Location: home.html?sid=" . $sid);
```

And then use the SID in the location bar via JavaScript to retrieve the user settings from **the same database**, will I expose my clients' hash?

Is there a better way, or a more standard way, to set and get user settings on the web?

P.S.: Unless you have a really good reason, I really, really, really, don't want to use SQL. I prefer to be able to read my databases, and I like the tangibility and versatility of XML.

**Edit:** After a little more research, I learned that PHP supports a system for storing SESSION[] variables. This is perfect for me because I am, in fact, using sessions!

The W3C says:

"A PHP session variable is used to store information about, or change settings for a user session. Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application."

Much better than exposing various data in the address bar. =)

Comment: you cant read your\a *SQL db ??

Comment: No, it's just... Well, an XML database is a _file_. That's it. SQL is an _interface_ that is completely unnecessary in my opinion, because both PHP and JavaScript are capable of reading XML via DOM.

Comment: you really dont understand data bases if you think they are unnecessary (name a site of any size that does not use them), and *sql uses files to.

Comment: I think I understand databases, and I think you misunderstood me. I meant that the _interface_ associated with SQL is complicated, and quite frankly, obsolete. Why would I use an entire API to access a database when I can just reference my own nice, neat, little file? For this project I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, and PHP. It would behoove me not to use any more layers of abstraction, no? I mean, what benefits could SQL offer that XML does not? I'm already writing in 1..2..3..4..5..6.. 6 languages. One more wouldn't hurt though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your DB file is inaccessable from HTTP (i.e. locked by a .htaccess or equivalent) and other protocols (i.e. not sitting in a directory accesable by anonymous FTP), the only risk is to (inadvertently) let the hash&salt be collected among a bunch of other user-related data and sent to your clients.

If you have requests equivalent to the SQL * selector, that might be somewhat of a problem. You might want to put the critical data into a different DB file and encapsulate the accesses in an interface dedicated to user registration and login, just to make sure no other piece of code will be able to grab them (even by mistake) from your main DB.